# What is the performance impact to Kafka consumers for re-keying a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Use case: We have a compacted topic which will use a UUID to track the lifecycle of an order.

Some of our services need to know how many orders any given account has at one time, to provide alerts and metrics (using Kafka Streams KTables). But since we are keying by UUID, the records will be produced across the topic partitions and not co-located.

My team's proposal is using a custom partition class so that we can use a UUID for the record key, but use the account Id value for the hashing algorithm for producing the records.

But our devOps/support team is concern about the tools support for custom partitioning class (such as Mirror Maker) screwing up which partition records are located in.

For the services that need this data co-located, we could use the Kafka streams re-key logic which will re-key the data in an internal topic to that service, but from my understanding, it comes with a performance impact. Is there any clear way of knowing what kind of impact it would be? Would it mean our processing time for each record is double?

Comment: You can rewrite the MirrorMaker handler class so it won't rearrange the partitions. But re-keying just adds extra load to the brokers for managing that data. The consumers would have to point at the new topic (and you should be using a different topic, otherwise, you're creating a processing loop)